# Problems to connect SSH with Google's VPC

Tags: google-compute-engine, vpc

I can't to connect by SSH with Google's VPC from my home, but I get to connect from my Public University.

I'm discarding this points: 
Problems with SSH, becausa i don't have problems to connect with another computer by ssh. 
I'm sure the problem is not SSH Key, because I get to connect from my Public University.

What did i do? 
I checked if the problem is Firewall, but I believe it's not that problem. See below the Firewall rule on VPC Google's: 
myrule  apply to all  Intervalos de IP: 192.168.0.0/24 tcp:22  Allow  1000  default

I did test the Ping. I did see that it's working.

```
PING 35.198.21.159 (35.198.21.159) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 35.198.21.159: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=24.6 ms
64 bytes from 35.198.21.159: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=29.0 ms
64 bytes from 35.198.21.159: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=26.0 ms
64 bytes from 35.198.21.159: icmp_seq=4 ttl=61 time=27.4 ms
^C
--- 35.198.21.159 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.623/26.773/29.024/1.645 ms
```

Looking the tracerout, i can see that the final point is not VPC's IP.
traceroute to 35.198.21.159 (35.198.21.159), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

```
 1  192.168.0.1  2.457 ms  3.457 ms  11.818 ms
 2  * * *
 3  187.122.188.1  14.157 ms  14.139 ms  14.496 ms
 4  200.167.43.21  23.555 ms  23.515 ms  23.476 ms
 5  200.244.216.46  22.159 ms  22.142 ms  23.242 ms
 6  200.244.216.167  19.398 ms  22.508 ms  22.752 ms
 7  201.73.52.38  12.922 ms  14.935 ms  16.819 ms
 8  108.170.251.66  14.762 ms 108.170.251.67  11.887 ms  13.945 ms
 9  209.85.245.50  29.488 ms 209.85.245.52  21.016 ms 216.239.43.16  19.189 ms
10  108.170.245.129  30.328 ms 108.170.245.225  28.877 ms  28.251 ms
11  72.14.232.163  27.519 ms 108.170.225.26  28.256 ms 209.85.247.47  29.109 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

For all that, can someone help me?

Comment: 1) How do you SSH (which command / tool)? 2) can you telnet port 22 from your home instead of ping or traceroute?